# Android Emulator USB Passthrough Won't Connect

Tags: android, windows, android-studio, usb, qemu

The standard Android Emulator that comes with Android Studio is a derivative of the QEMU CPU emulator. QEMU supports [USB passthrough](https://www.qemu.org/docs/master/system/usb.html). I.e. you can connect a USB device to your computer and the Android emulator should pick up that device as though it were connected to the emulated phone. I need to get this working so that I can debug transfer to a USB device ( [Trezor hardware wallet](https://trezor.io/) ) via the Android emulator.

Apparently, we can pass QEMU command line args to the Android emulator with the `-qemu` parameter. I pieced together this call which I think is correct:

`emulator -avd pixel_2_pie_9_0_-_api_28 -qemu -usb -device usb-host,vendorid=4617,productid=21441`

But, I get these errors:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\emulator>emulator -avd pixel_2_pie_9_0_-_api_28 -qemu -usb -device usb-host,vendorid=4617,productid=21441
> Failed to open /qemu.conf, err: 2
> Windows Hypervisor Platform accelerator is operational
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\emulator\qemu\windows-x86_64\qemu-system-x86_64.exe: libusb_kernel_driver_active: -12 [NOT_SUPPORTED]
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\emulator\qemu\windows-x86_64\qemu-system-x86_64.exe: libusb_kernel_driver_active: -12 [NOT_SUPPORTED]
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\emulator\qemu\windows-x86_64\qemu-system-x86_64.exe: libusb_kernel_driver_active: -12 [NOT_SUPPORTED]
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\emulator\qemu\windows-x86_64\qemu-system-x86_64.exe: libusb_kernel_driver_active: -12 [NOT_SUPPORTED]
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\emulator\qemu\windows-x86_64\qemu-system-x86_64.exe: libusb_kernel_driver_active: -12 [NOT_SUPPORTED]
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\emulator\qemu\windows-x86_64\qemu-system-x86_64.exe: libusb_kernel_driver_active: -12 [NOT_SUPPORTED]
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\emulator\qemu\windows-x86_64\qemu-system-x86_64.exe: libusb_kernel_driver_active: -12 [NOT_SUPPORTED]
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\emulator\qemu\windows-x86_64\qemu-system-x86_64.exe: libusb_kernel_driver_active: -12 [NOT_SUPPORTED]
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\emulator\qemu\windows-x86_64\qemu-system-x86_64.exe: libusb_kernel_driver_active: -12 [NOT_SUPPORTED]
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\emulator\qemu\windows-x86_64\qemu-system-x86_64.exe: libusb_kernel_driver_active: -12 [NOT_SUPPORTED]
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\emulator\qemu\windows-x86_64\qemu-system-x86_64.exe: libusb_kernel_driver_active: -12 [NOT_SUPPORTED]
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\emulator\qemu\windows-x86_64\qemu-system-x86_64.exe: libusb_kernel_driver_active: -12 [NOT_SUPPORTED]
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\emulator\qemu\windows-x86_64\qemu-system-x86_64.exe: libusb_kernel_driver_active: -12 [NOT_SUPPORTED]
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\emulator\qemu\windows-x86_64\qemu-system-x86_64.exe: libusb_kernel_driver_active: -12 [NOT_SUPPORTED]
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\emulator\qemu\windows-x86_64\qemu-system-x86_64.exe: libusb_kernel_driver_active: -12 [NOT_SUPPORTED]
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\emulator\qemu\windows-x86_64\qemu-system-x86_64.exe: libusb_kernel_driver_active: -12 [NOT_SUPPORTED]
> emulator: Saving state on exit with session uptime 51341 ms

The reason I think that this is correct is that if I unplug the device, or specify the incorrect vid/pid, I get a very different message with no errors:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\emulator>emulator -avd pixel_2_pie_9_0_-_api_28 -qemu -usb -device usb-host,vendorid=4617,productid=21441
> Failed to open /qemu.conf, err: 2
> Windows Hypervisor Platform accelerator is operational

In other words, I think that it is erroring because it recognises the device, tries to perform the passthrough, but can't. This might be a libusb error, but I do know that libusb does support this device. I've used it many times on this device. Also, I know that this device works with Android because I've written apps for it.

**Does anyone have USB passthrough working on the Android emulator?** If you've got it working with vanilla QEMU, that would also be very helpful. **What am I doing wrong?** **Do I need to create the device with any special properties?**

Comment: Please help me for the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65473066/removed-recycler-item-shows-up-again-after-deleting-other

Comment: Hi Christian, did you ever get this working for QEMU/Android Emulator on Windows?

Comment: No I didn't ...